# Use jQuery to hide if click outside a DIV

Tags: jquery

Hide #shoppingBag if you click outside of it but the toggle function should still work.

Thanks for any help.

This is my code:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.button-cart').click(function(){
          $('#shoppingBag').toggle();
        });

    });
```

HTML

```
<span class="button-cart">Warenkorb</span>

<div id="shoppingBag"></div>
```

Comment: Most likely a duplicate to: [How to detect a click outside an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/152975/1960455)

Comment: You should use an id pour your "button"